# Minecraft Server over PPTP: Client suddenly disconnects

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp, mtu

For the sake of sports experience, in order to have a public IP address on the home physical server, I rented a VDS in the nearest city with minimal characteristics. I then set up `pptpd` on that VDS. Next, on the physical server, I configured iproute2 and netplan to create a second gateway that leads to this PPTP server. Next, I set up port forwarding on the VDS and forwarded them to my home server.

Everything works. The only thing I notice is that there is such a problem on game servers: during the game, the player suddenly stops receiving data from the server at a random moment, but the server continues to receive data from the player. Because of what the player loses connection with the server and disconnects. On PocketMine-MP (written in PHP) it is solved by changing the MTU value, but there is no such option in Craftbukkit

Question: Is it possible to solve the problem with MTU globally, at the operating system level, and not at the game server level?

Comment: Does the player stop receiving _all_ data, or only the packets that exceed MTU? e.g. if the server runs `ping`, does the client still receive that? or if the client attempts to ping the server's internal (VPN) IP, does it receive replies  back?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes. Ping works fine. It seems the player stops receiving only the packets that exceed MTU, because after "Connection lost" he can just rejoin the server

Comment: What MTU does the "ppp" interface on both machines report? Does Minecraft use TCP or UDP? (I think Java edition uses TCP, right?)

Comment: @u1686_grawity Craftbukkit (Java) uses TCP. But PocketMine-MP (Mobile Minecraft, PHP) if my memory doesn't lie to me, it uses UDP